# ModX Evo file manager not working

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I'm running ModX Evo 1.0.5 and occured with a problem that file manager inside admin panel is not working. When I try loading it I get several alert messages displaying Parse error: error Parsing XML.. and at last it loads with this error

[image]

I have my assets folder CHMOD 777 and I have configured the File manager paths like [here](http://www.prodevtips.com/2009/07/29/modx-10-proper-configuration-of-file-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think these alerts have anything to do with configurations in the manager. I recently had lots of issues with the file browser in Evo. And i'm sure upgrading to Revo is not an option until modx releases some sort of migration utility (as it was in my case).

Have you tried re-running the setup over your current install? Might be a good opportunity to upgrade 1.0.6. (lol..dnt be like me forget to backup first)

If the file browser your talking about is the one MCPuck replacing my editor with [CKEditor](http://modx.com/extras/package/ckeditorforevo) did the trick.

Goood luck m8